# Continuity of the identity operator from weak to weak star topology

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a question in functional analysis.

Suppose $X$ is a normed space and $I:X'\rightarrow X'$ is an identity operator such that $If=f$ for $f$ in $X'$.

($X'$ is the dual space of $X$).

Show that $I$ is continuous from the weak topology to the weak* topology.

I intend to bound the seminorm induced by the weak* topology by the seminorm from the weak topology, but it seems that I need $X$ to be reflexive.

For the weak* topology on $X'$, $\forall x \in X, \rho_x:X'\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $\rho_x(f)=|f(x)|$. $\rho_x$ is a seminorm in $X'$.

For the weak topology on $X$, $\forall f \in X', \rho_f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $\rho_f(x)=|f(x)|$. $\rho_f$ is a seminorm in $X$.

For the weak topology in $X'$, it should be something like this:

For the weak topology on $X'$, $\forall F \in X'', \rho_F:X'\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $\rho_F(f)=|F(f)|$. $\rho_F$ is a seminorm in $X'$.

Can someone out there help?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you add how you define weak topology and weak star topology?

Comment: Great, thank you. Now I don't know if this helps but if you look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology#Other_properties_2) it says that the weak star topology is weaker than the weak topology on $X'$ (by definition). Hence if $O$ is an open set (in the weak star topology) the inverse image $I^{-1}O = O$ is open in the weak topology (by definition). Hence $I$ is continuous.

Comment: I will edit your title to add some more specific information about this question. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Sure. Thank you very much for your suggestion.:)